# Get Timestamp after Insert/Update

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

In azure table storage.  Is there a way to get the new timestamp value after an update or insert.  I am writing a 3-phase commit protocol to get table storage to support distributed transactions , and it involes multiple writes to the same entity.  So the operation order goes like this, `Read Entity`, `Write Entity (Lock Item)`, `Write Entity (Commit new values)`.  I would like to get the new timestamp after the lock item operation so I don't have to unecessarily read the item again before doing the commit new value operation.  So does any one know how to efficiently get the new timestamp value after a savechanges operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything special/extra. When you read your entity you will get an Etag for it. When you save that entity (setting someLock=true) that save will only succeed if nobody else have updated the entity since your read. Hence you know you have the lock. And then you can do your second write as you please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible.  I would use your own timestamp and/or guid to mark entries.

Comment: All I am trying to do two writes one after another, first time a lock and then the next time a commit.  I want to do this without having any reads in the middle.  An extra field is not going to help me prevent an extra read.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were trying to prevent others from writing to the same entity by doing timestamp comparison.  Can you elaborate why do you need to know the timestamp after it was inserted?

Comment: I am implementing my own distributed transaction method for Azure Table Storage since Table storage doesn't natively support it (I do not know why it doesn't?). I am performing 2 writes to the same entity.  The first write is a lock, I will basically set some property call IsLocked to true.  If that succeeds successfully, then all other roles will know not to write to that element because some other role currently has a lock on it.  Once I get the lock and I have locked all required rows involved in my distributed transaction I can then proceed to make the change to the entity.

Comment: Hence the need to get the timestamp after the first write.  So I then don't have to do a read to get the timestamp and then perform the write.  I am basically trying to save an unnecessary read operation.  Context.AttachTo("TableName", MyObj, "\*") where "\*" is my etag, i.e. disabling optimistic concurrency seems like an acceptable solution for me in this case but I am just wondering if there is a way to get the timestamp for future references.

Comment: Right, this is why I suggested to use your own custom Timestamp field and not use the Azure's internal "Timestamp" field.  This way, you can gen your own value before  every insert and update and your code will know what is its value.  To find out what Azure has generated for you, you need to do a read after insert/update

Comment: Dear friends, it is 12 years later and I am debugging a call to Task<IList<TableResult>> ExecuteBatchAsync(TableBatchOperation batch) and TableResul.Result obviously returns the TableEntity with exactly correctly set timestamp. So it looks like the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0 already can do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go back to the [Update REST API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179427.aspx), it does return the time that the response was generated.  It probably won't be exactly the same as the time stamp on the record, but it will be close I'm sure.

Comment: If it is not exact then won't 2nd update fail due to optimistic concurrency, is it possible to bypass the optimistic concurrency as well?  That will also work since when I get the lock, I can guarantee that no other process will attempt to update the entity.

Comment: Ok, in order to ignore Table Storages optimistic concurrency, instead of Updating a value like this

Answer (score 0):

You may need to hack your Azure table. drivers

In the Azure python lib (TableStorage) for example, the Timestamp is simply skipped over.

```
    # exclude the Timestamp since it is auto added by azure when
    # inserting entity. We don't want this to mix with real properties
    if name in ['Timestamp']:
        continue
```